# How to correlate CSRF token in URL path in JMeter

Tags: url, jmeter, token, csrf, correlation

While load testing a shopping site using JMeter, I encountered a issue with csrf token correlation. The csrf token is concatenated in the path part of the URL to add an item into the shopping cart. So it looks like http://www.aaaa.com/cart/add/type/item_id/123456/csrf_token/e4Edfar454fgsfgsgrrwbgqr/

How to correlate this csrf token that has to be submitted in the request URL path ie. the path part: /cart/add/type/item_id/123456/csrf_token/e4Edfar454fgsfgsgrrwbgqr/?
In jmeter it seems the path is fixed.

Thank you guys for your input!

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract CSRF token into a JMeter Variable called i.e. `token` with one of the following Post Processors:

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
   - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
2. Use aforementioned `token` variable in request path like:

   ```
   http://www.aaaa.com/cart/add/type/item_id/123456/csrf_token/${token}
   ```

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more information on bypassing CSRF protection in your JMeter test

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri. The obstacle is that in JMeter , the request path does not take variables. I can extract the whole path that is setup in the step prior to add to cart, and plug it in as ${rel_path} , it does not work that way. This is the error message: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 39  ${rel_path}

Comment: Request path does take variables. Something is wrong with your extraction and `rel_path` variable population - it has default value. You can check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

Comment: Thanks for your help , Dmitri, actually it is your post https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter that helped me figure out what went wrong: the regex. And in that page I have to correlate another two places.